# How to use Wordpress Trim Words Function

Tags: wordpress

i want to trim a single word i.e, Monday in wordpress, how can i trim this word?

```
$my_title = get_the_title();
echo wp_trim_words($my_title, 1, null );
```

the title coming from database Monday So i want to trim Monday to Mo or M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wp_trim_words() will works easily without any problems. You can use it with below sample code:

```
echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 1, '' );
```

But do note that it will trim the first character in whole post/page title, not regconize the date in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that `wp_trim_words()` works that way. I'd recommend just using regex and `preg_match()`:

```
$my_title = get_the_title();
```

to get the first character:

```
$regex = '/(.?)/';
```

or to get the first two characters, change the variable to this:

```
$regex = '/(.?)./';
```

Then get the matches for the regex pattern:

```
preg_match($regex, $my_title, $matches);
```

Echo out the first one:

```
echo $matches[0];
```